# CoordinatorLayout anchor view wrong position after change visibility for anchor-to-View

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I use `CoordinatorLayout` for this layout:
[image]

There are `RecycleView` with `BottomSheetBehavior` and `AnchorView` - `View` which anchored to first item in `RecycleView`.

When I scroll `RecycleView` to top (I listen this with `BottomSheetCallback`) I change anchorId in `AnchorView`:

```
anchorId = View.NO_ID
```

And when I scroll my `RecycleView` down I bind `AnchorView` to first item again. And this works well.

But when I change visibility in FirstItem view I have this problem: The anchored view has wrong position on the screen. (If I scroll list the position is valid again).

**How to fix it?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stop using any animations for itemView and it fix my problem.